# Not able to publish using facebook api

Tags: c#, facebook

i am retrieving access token using

```
 if (window.location.hash.length == 0) {
            url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" +
                     appId + "&redirect_uri=" + window.location +
                     "&response_type=token&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream";
                       window.location.href(url);

        } else {
            accessToken = window.location.hash.substring(1);
}
```

and publishing the feed using

```
 FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(strAccessToken);
                Dictionary<string, object> postMessage = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                postMessage["message"] = "test post from facebook app";
                postMessage["link"] ="http://google.com";
                postMessage["name"] = "";
                postMessage["caption"] = "";
                postMessage["description"] = "test post from facebook app";

                object result = client.Post("me/feed", postMessage);
```

i am gettig the error 'unable to connect to remote server'

What could be the wrong here?

Comment: Is your appId correct? That's always the first thing I check. You could also try debugging and getting `url` then trying to test it through the browser. Facebook usually will throw something at you if it is correct, and if it isn't then you know were to go from there

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the token in 'accessToken' but passing 'strAccessToken'?  Could it be that simple?